# Naviagtion Drawer Add buttons on list view in android

Tags: android, listview, button, navigation-drawer

I want to add buttons in each list view  of the navigation Drawer. How can we add the button over there can any body provide example/sample code. I took the sample example from Android Developers..

Thanks In Advance

Comment: use a custom listview

Comment: can you provide sample example...

Comment: search on google or stackoverflow first

Comment: k fine...meanwhile you can provide me...

Comment: can fine..can  you provide me that links...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Check this: http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android and http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just use this answer I explained how to design custom listView....
In the below class i used two textview for the replacement of that two you just use a Two

**Button in tha layout and use this custom adapter**

like....

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);
mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and then use this code...

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());
    text2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // you just put your Logic here And use this custom adapter to
            // load your Data By using this particular custom adapter to
            // your listview

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

}
```

All the best